# Hide options from select box dynamically (depending on the value of first select)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got two select fields as

select field1:

```
<select id="minprice" required name="minprice" class="sell-textfield">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="3">less than 10 lakh</option>
            <option value="1000000">10 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="2000000">20 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="3000000">30 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="4000000">40 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="5000000">50 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="6000000">60 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="7000000">70 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="8000000">80 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="9000000">90 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="10000000">1 Crore</option>
            <option value="12000000">1.2 Crores</option>
            <option value="14000000">1.4 Crores</option>
            <option value="16000000">1.6 Crores</option>
            <option value="18000000">1.8 Crores</option>
            <option value="20000000">2 Crores</option>
            <option value="22500000">2.25 Crores</option>
            <option value="30000000">3 Crores</option>
            <option value="35000000">3.5 Crores</option>
            <option value="40000000">4 Crores</option>
            <option value="45000000">4.5 Crores</option>
            <option value="50000000">5 Crores</option>
            <option value="60000000">6 Crores</option>
            <option value="70000000">7 Crores</option>
            <option value="80000000">8 Crores</option>
            <option value="90000000">9 Crores</option>
            <option value="100000000">10 Crores</option>
            <option value="150000000">15 Crores</option>
            <option value="200000000">20 Crores</option>
            <option value="300000000">30 Crores</option>
            <option value="400000000">40 Crores</option>
            <option value="500000000">50 Crores</option>
            <option value="12345678901234567890">Above 50 Crores</option>
        </select>
```

select field2:

```
<select id="maxprice" required name="maxprice" class="sell-textfield">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1000000">10 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="2000000">20 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="3000000">30 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="4000000">40 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="5000000">50 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="6000000">60 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="7000000">70 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="8000000">80 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="9000000">90 Lakhs</option>
            <option value="10000000">1 Crore</option>
            <option value="12000000">1.2 Crores</option>
            <option value="14000000">1.4 Crores</option>
            <option value="16000000">1.6 Crores</option>
            <option value="18000000">1.8 Crores</option>
            <option value="20000000">2 Crores</option>
            <option value="22500000">2.25 Crores</option>
            <option value="30000000">3 Crores</option>
            <option value="35000000">3.5 Crores</option>
            <option value="40000000">4 Crores</option>
            <option value="45000000">4.5 Crores</option>
            <option value="50000000">5 Crores</option>
            <option value="60000000">6 Crores</option>
            <option value="70000000">7 Crores</option>
            <option value="80000000">8 Crores</option>
            <option value="90000000">9 Crores</option>
            <option value="100000000">10 Crores</option>
            <option value="150000000">15 Crores</option>
            <option value="200000000">20 Crores</option>
            <option value="300000000">30 Crores</option>
            <option value="400000000">40 Crores</option>
            <option value="500000000">50 Crores</option>
            <option value="12345678901234567890">Above 50 Crores</option>
        </select>
```

Now I am trying to hide the options from maxprice which are lesser than minprice's selected option. So I have created a function on minprice change as:

```
$("#minprice").change(function() {
var i;  
for(i=1;i<=32;i++){
    if($('#maxprice option').eq(i).val()<$(this).val()) {               
        $('#maxprice option').eq(i).hide();
    }else{
        $('#maxprice option').eq(i).show();

    }
}
});
```

The function hides 1 crore, 1.2 crore from maxprice when given 20lakhs in minprice
hides 2 crore, 2.25 crore from maxprice when given 30 lakhs in minprice. and so on.

I have checked everything and can't find what's the problem.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes you can,I have done that before. But this time I am having the problem that some options that shouldn't be hidden gets hidden.Control goes to if condition when it should go to else.

Comment: have you tried to parse the value to integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this: [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/IxayOYE/1/edit)

```
$("#minprice").change(function() {

  var i = $('option:selected', this).index();
  $("#maxprice option").show();
  $("#maxprice option:lt("+ i +")").hide();

});
```

Comment: @Aman I do't understand. You desired to hide the options, not me :) what's the issue?

Comment: Show a demo that reproduces the issue. What browser you use?

Answer (score 1):

so the both select have the same options, i think you can do like this:

```
$("#minprice").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $option = $this.find('option[value='+$this.val()+']');
    var curIndex = $option.index();
    $('#maxprice option:lt('curIndex')').hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, is this what you want? and @Roko C. Buljan's is better

Comment: did you use size on the select element? but I dont see, I guess the issue in your css

Comment: and you can try .css({'visibility':'hidden'});  instead of .hide();

Comment: I really don't know what you want, sorry ~

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#minprice').on('change',function(){
        var min = $(this);
        var max = $('#maxprice');
        var minSel = this.selectedIndex;

        max.find('option').removeAttr('disabled').removeAttr('selected');
        max.find('option:eq('+minSel+')').prevAll('option').attr('disabled',true);
    });
});
</script>
```